# 403 Forbidden Error When I visit Admin after adding new Theme to Magento 2.2.3

Tags: theme, magento2.2.3

[image: I get the error when I visit admin]  I get this error when I visit http://domain/admin after I have added a new theme to magento 2.2.3.
I already run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` but the error is still there. 
 The error in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` is `AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/magento2admin`
How do I go about solving this error?

Comment: magento version you have 2.2. all the modules and themes are probably incompatible with this outdated version. latest magento is 2.3.3

Comment: looks like you have permissions issues. check your folder

Comment: It turns out I had issue with the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try deleting from the directory files:
\var\cache
\generated\code
And then run:
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

If its is not working

**

```
Try deleting from the directory files:
\var\cache
\generated\code
And then run:
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

**

```
Then try to This.
Select luma theme on dashboard and then remove your theme from database. 
Upgrade database
Again select your theme from dashboard
Repeat all commands like static content deployment etc.
Hope it will works fine.
```

-